# Need to get mail.google.com IP address(es)

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, gmail, ip-address

I have a server which is locked down to only allow access from specific IP addresses.

Emails sent from this server contain images. When viewed in gmail (http://mail.google.com) the images are obviously blocked as the ip of http://mail.google.com is not allowed via the firewall.

Is there any way I can obtain a list of IPs that the gmail webmail uses?

I have done a DNS lookup which has returned:

```
74.125.227.149
74.125.227.150
```

But i'd be surprised if these remain the same or if the public IP is one of these (as they're probably the IPs of their load balancers).

If it's of any use the server I have is on AWS

Comment: aren't the images loaded client-side by each recipients browser? I'd be surprised if mail.google.com would be the only client trying to access them.

Answer (score 1):

How are you filtering these requests? It's likely there'll be a way to instead filter by domain, which would be a much more maintainable and practical approach to this. If not, you might want to pass through a wider range of requests, and filter them more carefully on your server yourself.

In general, although you can get a list of current ips for gmail from DNS servers and filter for those (some information on this is available at https://support.google.com/a/answer/60764?hl=en, although primarily for use in managing your own SMTP config, not for filtering IPs generally), I would avoid then hardcoding those if you can. They're likely to change unpredictably, as Google shifts their internal infrastructure about, and this approach is never going to be very reliable (and will unpredictably intermittently fail, when it does break).

Filter by domain instead, or allow access from a wider range of request sources and find another way to filter to provide the security you're looking for (e.g. allow anybody access to your web server's port only, and then lock down the available paths within that).

Comment: Yeh that's the ideal solution but AWS firewall only allows IPs. Got a feeling the only way may be via a script to lookup the current IP and add to the AWS firewall

Comment: Yeah, ok, that sounds like a reasonable solution, and the AWS security groups are very nicely automatable. I'd just make sure you're polling frequently enough that you don't start hitting issues from lag (and maybe logging changes so you can see how much of an issue it actually is?)